# Cannot add to repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Here is error when i use git add .

```
 $ git add .
    error: short read while indexing .editorconfig
    error: .editorconfig: failed to insert into database
    error: unable to index file '.editorconfig'
    fatal: adding files failed
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have another file named the same but with different case, such as `.Editorconfig`? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257266

Comment: @WillWalsh my .ediconfig

Comment: root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false

[*.{yml,yaml}]
indent_size = 2

Comment: Are you using Git for Windows? As described in the URL I sent, this can be due Git trying to add identical filenames with different case.

Comment: yes i am using git for windows

Comment: Is there another file named .editorconfig, but with differing case?

Answer (score 4):

This (`error: short read while indexing name`) happens when Git finds a file of the given name, gets information from the OS *about* that file, and goes to add that file to the index aka staging-area.  Git:

- uses the file's name to open the file;
- reads the contents of the file; and
- discovers that although the system said the file was at exactly *N<sub>1</sub>* bytes long, Git was only able to read *N<sub>0</sub>* bytes, where *N<sub>0</sub>* < *N<sub>1</sub>*.

On Git-for-Windows when using WSL, there's a new feature whereby you can allow the system to store two files that differ only in the *case* of some names, e.g., both `readme.txt` *and* `README.TXT`.  Normally Windows only allows *one* such name, and once the name exists, using any variant—including `ReAdMe.TxT` or `reaDME.tXT` or whatever—gets you the one file.  Git-for-Windows makes too much use of this assumption, which WSL has now broken.

The solution for now is:

- don't do this, and/or
- don't use Windows.<sup>1</sup>

Eventually, the Git-for-Windows folks will build a version of Git-for-Windows that handles the problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>The macOS folks may snicker at the Windows folks here, but macOS has similar issues.  In some ways the macOS issues can be worse (NFC vs NFD names), though in other ways the Windows issues are worse (can't create files named `aux.c` and `aux.h`).  Git needs a proper general mechanism here, really, but in some ways this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu and I have this problem?

Comment: @no_one: I've never used Kubuntu, but being based on Ubuntu, it generally *should not* have these kinds of problems. It's possible they've added a Windows file system and added this problematic Windows feature, though.

Comment: I am using docker on window and I had this problem. I have two same files with different case of the name but I could only see one file in vscode. I opened the folder in file explorer and I saw those two files. I deleted the file with the wrong case name and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the file causing the problem
2. Copy-paste the file's content to a temporary file
3. Revert changes on the problematic file
4. Run your "git add" command, then

- If "git add" succeeded, copy-paste content from temporary file to the
  problematic file, then run your "git add" command again, it should work.
- If "git add" failed because another file causing same 1-4 problem, repeat steps for the new problematic file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this file NUL in my project folder,
that could not be moved or deleted or read at all.
It is like kind of bug.

When I tried to move the file NUL
It showed error like internal failure number 8x????

### My solution:

I replicate my project folder without the file NUL

Then the failure with git add .  is gone

Answer (score -1):

In my case the folder was on a Mac, stored in iCloud & also being backed up via git. The File API sometimes removes files from disk. I opened the folder in Finder and clicked the download button, then it worked.